# Ionic app, can't login with facebook as android app

Tags: android, facebook-login, ionic-framework

I am using the ionic framework to build a facebook-based mobile app.

It works great in the browser, however, when I build it for android, I cannot get past the login screen.

When I run the app on my phone, and press the "login with facebook" button, nothing happens, even though I have facebook installed on my android phone.

I used Facebook's guide for installing the sdk, and have this in my index.html file:

```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'my_app_id',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });

      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log(response);
            console.log('Logged in');
          } else {
            FB.login();
          }
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

This works on web perfectly. Only when using it as a packaged .apk file on Android, it does not launch the facebook app.

Comment: you may want to include some code and a more detailed description.

Comment: Did you install cordova facebook plugin?

Comment: I couldn't find a cordova facebook plugin that worked for facebook sdk v1.0

Answer (score 0):

i think its not possible to use direct facebook js sdk on building mobile apps. try use ngCordova. it have a plugin for facebook

[ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Facebook)